# opencsv does not return the complete values in original csv file

Tags: java, csv

I write this code to to take info. from csv file and this file contain more than 
8000 rows but when I run the program it return only 575 row. Can any one help me with this please and also need to know how to compare time fields of the consecutive lines, I need     to compare these values and rearrange the data according to the smallest one and then add a     new row with specific value according specific condition.

```
/* this is the code */ 
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader;


public class CSVdata {

/**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {




        try{
            FileReader klausuar = new FileReader(
"klausurphase_propa_anonym.csv");
            CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(klausuar);
            String [] nextLine;
            reader.readNext();
            while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
                // nextLine[] is an array of values from the line


                System.out.println(nextLine[2] + " **  " + nextLine[3] + " **  " + 
nextLine[4] + " **  " ) ;
            }
        klausuar.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}
}
```

Comment: please show 570-580 rows in your csv file, and in code, catch ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 possible answers here:

1. Your CSV is badly formatted (try opening it in Excel and see the actual size)
2. Since your program only prints the lines on the screen, perhaps your console (either Eclipse or system) has a limited buffer which cannot display more than that.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answers the problem was with console has limited buffer , I tried to print less 
columns and it show more rows. There is no answers regarding the other questions.